# Swapping Fairy Lights Power supply/driver

Tags: power-supply, led-driver

Hi I have some fairy lights which work just fine. My only issue is they don't remember what pattern I set them to after turning them off so they always turn on in the demo mode.

[image: Current supply/driver]

I've been looking at alternative supplies/drivers but I'm not sure if they'll work. The current supply says 32v out at 3.6w power. I can find supplies that are 3.6w power but the output voltage is 34/35v.

Would the lights still work with the higher voltage or would it blow the bulbs?

Comment: No guarantees, but : Very likely to be OK. I'd be rather surprised if anything was that closely toleranced. || If that's a DC output you could add 3 x silicon diodes in series to drop voltage by about 2 V.  (1N400x, where x doesn't matter here (4001-4007))

Comment: More information is required for us to understand what you are trying to do and what you have. What light pattern do you want? - all always on? Is that the old driver? More ... ?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon the lights work fine. They just don't remember the pattern I set them to. On the supply it's labelled slow glow. They fade in and out. However if I unplug them or turn the switch off when I next plug them in they are back in the demo mode and I have to cycle through the patterns to get to the one I want. I've linked the plug socket to a motion sensor so they come on when motion detected but it's the wrong pattern.

Comment: What you show us is just the Power supply. Yet your question is more about the actual logic inside your fairy lights. You can't make the lights remember last state in the plug socket. Please provide some info about the actual device.

Comment: You could use the motion sensor to operate a relay that disconnects the lights AFTER the controller. || A not to hard circuit could pulse the mode button N times after power up. [An Arduino for a few dollars, or a CD4017 and package of Schmitt inverters, or ...)

Comment: @S_G I think there's some confusion. The picture shows the power supply/driver. Its a single unit. The LED string just plugs into it and the button on the plug cycles through the patterns there's no logic inside the lights. This particular supply/driver doesn't have a memory function. The alternatives I've found online all have slightly different output voltages but do have memory functions.

Comment: After @RussellMcMahon original comment I ordered one of the alternative supply/driver units I found online with a memory function which has arrived today and so far is doing the trick. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ordered an alternative supply/driver unit which arrived today. [See here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B09LVL94H4?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details)

Its a slightly higher output voltage but so far is working just fine and the memory function works so it no longer defaults to a strobe/demo mode when the motion sensor trigger the plug socket.